# print different html elements based on $ values

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to edit a page of a WordPress theme so that one of three paragraphs available on the page should come out with a box around it. There's a row of three similar feature boxes and only one out of three should be printed with this box around it: the business box.

Now, since I'm tired of debunking all the php code and write simple and dull html over it, I wanted to try to do it in a dynamic way: when a particular condition verifies, then that box will be printed in a particular way.

Now, I've already edited the code of the page so that a different set of icons could be used instead of the default one (the one which comes with the theme) as you can see from the code attached, so I thought: "why not setting that specific icon code as a condition to activate the box design?"

I searched for the syntax of the "if" statement and tried to write something in the page: now the site didn't explode and that's a good thing in the first place, but the edit didn't work as I was afraid of.

I am not even sure if the "if" is the correct way because there's basically a repetition of the same element (an array?) but, at the same time, my knowledge is limited as I said.

so this is the code of the entire page: you'll notice my part in a second

```
function hestia_features_content( $hestia_features_content, $is_callback = false ) {
if ( ! $is_callback ) {
    ?>
    <div class="hestia-features-content">
    <?php
}
if ( ! empty( $hestia_features_content ) ) :

    $hestia_features_content = json_decode( $hestia_features_content );
    if ( ! empty( $hestia_features_content ) ) {
        $i = 1;
        echo '<div class="row">';
        foreach ( $hestia_features_content as $features_item ) :
            $icon = ! empty( $features_item->icon_value ) ? apply_filters( 'hestia_translate_single_string', $features_item->icon_value, 'Features section' ) : '';
            $image = ! empty( $features_item->image_url ) ? apply_filters( 'hestia_translate_single_string', $features_item->image_url, 'Features section' ) : '';
            $title = ! empty( $features_item->title ) ? apply_filters( 'hestia_translate_single_string', $features_item->title, 'Features section' ) : '';
            $text = ! empty( $features_item->text ) ? apply_filters( 'hestia_translate_single_string', $features_item->text, 'Features section' ) : '';
            $link = ! empty( $features_item->link ) ? apply_filters( 'hestia_translate_single_string', $features_item->link, 'Features section' ) : '';
            $color = ! empty( $features_item->color ) ? $features_item->color : '';
            $choice = ! empty( $features_item->choice ) ? $features_item->choice : 'customizer_repeater_icon';
            ?>
            <!-- <div class="col-md-4 feature-box"> -->

<?php
if  ($icon_value == "&#xe015;") {
    echo '<div class="cherry-plain col-md-4 feature-box">';
} else {
    echo '<div class="col-md-4 feature-box">';
} 
?>

            <!-- <div class="col-md-4 feature-box"> -->
                <div class="info hestia-info">
                    <?php if ( ! empty( $link ) ) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $link ); ?>">
                        <?php
                        endif;

                        switch ( $choice ) {
                            case 'customizer_repeater_image':
                                if ( ! empty( $image ) ) {
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="card card-plain">
                                        <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $image ); ?>"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                break;
                            case 'customizer_repeater_icon':
                                if ( ! empty( $icon ) ) {
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="icon" <?php echo ( ! empty( $color ) ? 'style="color:' . $color . '"' : '' ); ?>>
                                       <!-- <i class="fa <?php echo esc_html( $icon ); ?>"></i> -->
                                            <span style="font-size: 33px;" data-icon="<?php echo esc_html( $icon ); ?>"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                        ?>
                        <?php if ( ! empty( $title ) ) : ?>
                            <h4 class="info-title"><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></h4>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if ( ! empty( $link ) ) : ?>
                    </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ( ! empty( $text ) ) : ?>
                        <p><?php echo wp_kses_post( html_entity_decode( $text ) ); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
            if ( $i % 3 == 0 ) {
                echo '</div><!-- /.row -->';
                echo '<div class="row">';
            }
            $i++;

        endforeach;
        echo '</div>';
    }// End if().
endif;
if ( ! $is_callback ) {
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
}
```

from a mere grammatical POV it shouldn't be completely wrong, because if you switch  `if  ($icon_value == "&#xe015;")` with `if  ($icon_value = "&#xe015;")` something works, in the sense that it changes ALL the elements, which is not what I want.

I just want to change that element WHERE that condition verifies: I thought there was a WHERE function but it doesn't appear to exist in the form that I was thinking..

anyway: how can I correct this?

Comment: `if  ($icon_value = "&#xe015;")` will always work because you are setting $icon_value equal to "&#xe015;", therefor it's always true.  Using = sets a variable.  Using == compares the values, and using === compares the values AND types.

Comment: yes @DanielC, this I already knew

Answer (score 0):

I think you either want to check `$icon`, or `$features_item->icon_value`... `$icon_value` doesn't seem to be used anywhere on the page.  Change:

```
if($icon_value == "&#xe015;") {
```

to

```
if($icon == "&#xe015;") {
```

And if that doesn't work... try

```
if($features_item->icon_value == "&#xe015;") {
```

A solid trick of the trade is to use `echo '<pre>'; var_dump( $icon_value ); echo '</pre>';` to see what your variable equals!

Comment: I had already checked all three alternatives before the post but nothing changed.
I want to use that var dump, I'll let you know thnks

Comment: ok, I think I know where the problem is:
if you use var_dump with $icon_value it returns "NULL" but if you use it with $icon it gives: string(3) "".
Which means in my opinion that it isn't able to read correctly the value "&#xe015;".
Now, I thought I would use a sort of esc_html() function but I am just guessing.. what is it in your opinion?

Comment: I think you are better off with something on the lines of `htmlspecialchars_decode()`.  So maybe `if( htmlspecialchars_decode( $icon ) == '&#xe015 )`.  But try to `var_dump( htmlspecialchars_decode( $icon ) )` first to see.

Comment: thanks @Daniel C, I will try your suggestion straight away because I was right: it's special characters' fault. 
I tried to switch with an arbitrary word and it works!!!
Wow, I'm so proud: at least my first php script was not "Hello World" :) someone give me an upvote !! thanks

Comment: You are welcome!  You did a great job on the coding.. that var_dump with be invaluable to you.  Good luck.

Comment: in the end I realized that may be the problem came from how the Wordpress Customizer itself handles the values you type in the fields: those characters all returned "" after immission. So, I decided to switch method and use a more classic "class" instead of "data-icon": this way I can insert just plain text and it always works. Thank you: without htmlspecialchars_decode I couln't have done it!